# How to call images to a different view in xcode using variables

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am currently working on a project in Xcode 4.4 with objective-c not in cocos2d where I have a view called GameView and a class called Characters. In the GameView have, well, the game, this is the scene in which you play the game. In the Characters, all the characters images and powers or anything unique to them are called. **I want it so that I can choose a character in CharacterSelect page and then the character that I selected is the character that is in the GameView and that I am controlling.** Right now I am just working with the images. In the GameView I am basically trying to set up a way to call an image of the corresponding character from the Characters class. If I could I would have an animation of the character but I'm just going to go step by step. All I want is the corresponding image for the character while he's facing right
Here is my code in my GameView.m for the function to basically create the image, and I know I need to call the image file from a variable in Characters. bluebox is like defined in the .h as a UIImageView and really it just contains all the things the character can do... such as the left and right buttons allows it to move and so on...

```
        -(void)createCharacter
 {
     bluebox = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
           CGRectMake(70, 100, 150, 130)];
     bluebox = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

 }
```

In my Characters.m I made an NSString in my .h of Characters in it is called lookingRight1... And then for one of my characters I have this

```
-(void)megaMan
{
 lookingRight1 = @"MegaManRight1.png";
}
```

Now I suppose I'd need to call looking right. I'm actually confusing my self trying to write this, so please help, if you don't get confused also. I don't have really much code for my CharacterSelect page but what I do have just links a particular button labeled with a character name to the GameView.
If you could please help I'd be extremely thankful. I think that it would help if you could show a mock second character also so that I can see what to do to get the character I want...

Sorry If this is confusing to you.